# Suggestion in hierarchy and normalization in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalization, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

Brief:
We are going to pull over huge set of data from n number of different servers to one server. Its going to have a billion of records in one table.

Existing:
That table is having about 80 to 90 columns, for ex:

```
ID, ParentID, L1H1, L1H2,L1H3,L2H1,L2H2,L3H3......
```

As you can see, this is hierarchial data in which it self represent itself ie parent item is also in this table.

My Ideas:

1. I'm going to use HierarchyID which is in-built in SQL server.
2. Segregating data and save it across with a different table ie L1
   values are separately, L2 values are separate etc..,

Could someone suggest whether am i going in correct way? Or is there something i can do better?
or keep the source table as it is and create views on top of it would be better?

I'm really concerned about the optimization of fetching data/ showing it another application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider Partition and I believe it's not supported all SQL Server editions ...Partitioning large tables can have lot of benefits, read here 
 [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx][1]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx%5d%5b1%5d)